# Проблемы с QString в PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, qtcreator, pyside2, qstring

Приложение PySide2 не распознает QString в файле формирования интерфейса.

Код формируется утилиткой pyside2-uic:

```
################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'RoleChooseDialog.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.0
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

# Первая строка кода с QString()
self.comboBox.addItem(QString())
...
```

Выдается такая ошибка:

```
File "<...>.py", line 27, in setupUi
self.comboBox.addItem(QString())
NameError: name 'QString' is not defined
```

Что я забыл установить/подключить/нажать/поставить/импортнуть?

З.Ы. Запускаюсь из под QtCreator 5.14.0  Windows 10.
Под Ubuntu 16.04 такой ошибки не было

**Временное решение (ака "костыль")**
Работает, если добавляю в эти сгенерированные файлы, в первую строку `QString = str`, что, конечно, "красиво", но вопрос остался )

Comment: `self.comboBox.addItem(QString())` это `pyside2-uic` сформировал пример с `QString` или вы сами добавили? В PyQt/PySide строки QString ведь хорошо заменяются питоничьими `str`

Comment: @gil9red uic так сгенерировал

Comment: Тогда, костыль `QString = str` обоснован :) Как вариант, вы можете обернуть `pyside2-uic` -- после вызова `pyside2-uic` вызвать свой скрипт, что заменит `QString()` на `""`. Либо удалите из QComboBox на форме строку, заполняйте его в коде

Comment: @gil9red собственно так и делаю - то есть оборачиваю pyside2-uic своим скриптом. В коде заполнять лень )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В интернетах пишут, что есть такое поведение утилиты `pyside2-uic`.
Исправляется либо установкой утилиты другой версии (ранней и непропатченной), либо написанием небольшого скрипта, который подставляет в сгенерированные uic-ом файлы, в первую строку запись

```
QString = Str
```

Второй вариант предпочтителен, поскольку ошибка генерации ui-файла возникает периодически даже в новых версиях pyside2-uic. Кроме того, в результате работы этой утилиты возникают и другие артефакты, которые удобно исправлять в функции-препроцессоре, пример которой представлен ниже.

Пример скрипта:

```
# dirs - список директорий в которых находятся ui-файлы для внесения исправлений
def preprocessing(dirs=[]):
    if len(dirs) == 0:
        dirs = ['.']

    # Бежим по полученным директориям
    for dir in dirs:
        # Пробегаемся по содержимому директории
        for f in listdir(dir):
            fullPath = path.join(dir, f)            
            if path.isfile(fullPath):
                filename, ext = path.splitext(f)
                if ext == '.ui':
                    # если файл типа ui, то берем его имя и добавляем к нему
                    # расширение py и префикс ui_. 
                    # В данный файл утилита pyside2-uic будет сохранять результат своей работы
                    uicOutputFile = 'ui_' + filename + '.py'
                    tmpUicOutputFile = '_'+uicOutputFile
                    system('pyside2-uic {} > {}'.format(fullPath, tmpUicOutputFile))

                    # Открываем файлы для чтения и записи исправлений
                    newfile = open(uicOutputFile,  'w')
                    sourcefile = open(tmpUicOutputFile, 'r')

                    # Первой строкой добавляем исправление
                    newfile.write("QString = str\n")

                    # Добавляем все остальные строки
                    for line in sourcefile:
                        newfile.write(line)

                    sourcefile.close()
                    # Удаляем "порченный" файл
                    remove(tmpUicOutputFile)

                    newfile.close()
```

Данный скрипт следует вызывать в самом начале файла-точки входа в приложение.
Пусть точка входа это файл main.py, тогда вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
# myuic - файл в котором находится наша функция препроцессинга
import myuic

# вызов
myuic.preprocessing()

# далее все остальные импорты и сама функция __main__
import ...
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    ...
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже на эти грабли наступил. Но решил просто на пустую строку заменять:

```
sed -i 's/QString()/""/g' <ui_file>.py
```

Плюс там есть пара других ошибок в новом uic:

1. если на форме есть `QDateTimeEdit`, то он забывает `QDate` добавить в список `import`.
2. если есть `promoted widget` то тоже криво генерятся `import` для них.

*Свежий апдейт на qt5-tools 5.14.1 принёс изменения:*

1. Проблема с QString ушла, теперь всё хорошо
2. Если файл с классом `Promoted widget` был в отдельном каталоге, то раньше всё было совсем плохо. Теперь проблема только в том, что разделитель каталогов так и остаётся "/". Приходится руками заменять на точку, которую ожидает Python (команда для `sed` аналогичная, как выше, но там надо привязаться к имени каталога, чтобы лишнего изменить)
3. QDate так и забывает добавлять в список импорта

Answer (score 0):

> PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.addItem(text[, userData=None])
>
> Parameters
>
> text – unicode
>
> userData – object

Добавляет элемент в выпадающий список с заданным **текстом** и с указанными данными пользователя (хранится в UserRole). Элемент добавляется в список существующих элементов.

Замените `self.comboBox.addItem(QString())` на `self.comboBox.addItem('')`

Comment: Я не могу заменить - это результат работы утилиты pyside2-uic из командной строки. Вот временный костыль добавил, но если изменю ui-файл, то опять придется костыль добавлять